# How to merge these syntactically correctly if possible? R CSV files

Tags: r, list, csv, matrix

So I've got a list of hundreds of CSV files (each being a matrix of 0's and 1's) loaded in through this

```
CSVs <- list.files("C:/filepath", pattern=".csv")
```

And I was before testing for number of columns that have exactly 6 instances of a 1 using this:

```
sapply(CSVs, function(x) sum(colSums(read.csv(x) == 1, na.rm = TRUE) == 6))
```

I now need to measure the vertical distance between the top-most 1 and the bottom-most one in the matrix (simply the difference between rows), and I've found this code which I believe should work:

```
diff(range(which(rowSums(matrix) > 0)))
```

But I just can't figure out how to utilise this syntactically to apply over all the CSV matrices in the way I was doing before.

Would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` in the same way like how you are using it before :

```
sapply(CSVs, function(x) diff(range(which(rowSums(read.csv(x)) > 0))))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, I was being silly and jumbling my brackets up.